# Camel jetty rest methods on 2 ports and protocols

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, jetty

is that possible to do this in camel:
2 rest services standing on jetty, first by http (for example on port 1234) and second https (for example on port 4321), how can I configure it? Is that possible?

Effect which i need to receive (example urls):

```
http://localhost:1234/firstHttpMethod
http://localhost:1234/secondHttpMethod
https://localhost:4321/firstHttpsMethod
https://localhost:4321/secondHttpsMethod
```

For this moment when I'm trying to add 2 routes, only second is working. How to solve that problem (I have a think to do 2 rest services - first on jetty, second on something else, but its not good conception).

code looks like this:

```
camelContext.addRoutes(firstJettyBuilder());
camelContext.addRoutes(secondJettyBuilder());

protected RouteBuilder firstJettyBuilder()
{
    return new RouteBuilder()
    {
        @Override
        public void configure()
            throws Exception
        {

            restConfiguration()
                .component("jetty")
                .host("localhost") 
                .port(42300) 
                .scheme("https") 
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.enableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES");

            configureSSL();
        }

        private void configureSSL()
        {
            final JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = camelContext.getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);

            final Map<String, Object> sslSocketConnectorProperties = new HashMap<>();

            sslSocketConnectorProperties.put("keyStorePath", KEYSTORE);
            sslSocketConnectorProperties.put("trustStorePath", KEYSTORE);

            sslSocketConnectorProperties.put("keyStorePassword", KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);
            sslSocketConnectorProperties.put("trustStorePassword", KEYSTORE_PASSWORD);

            jettyComponent.setSslSocketConnectorProperties(sslSocketConnectorProperties);
        }
    };
}
protected RouteBuilder createPosJettyBuilder()
{
    return new RouteBuilder()
    {
        @Override
        public void configure()
            throws Exception
        {

            restConfiguration()
                .component("jetty")
                .host("localhost") 
                .port(42302) 
                .scheme("http")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.enableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES");

        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Please provide also your route config.

Comment: What do you mean second is working? Do both routes come up when you start the camelcontext? Only one route?

Comment: Depends on order of calling first or second jettyBuilder i can only connect to one of services

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: I don't thnik this is possible in the same Camel context, because of reasons that I can call bugs. It might be possible with different contexts.

---

Here are some observations after debugging this.

1st try: as in the question.

Camel uses the same Jetty endpoint for both configurations. The second RouteBuilder overwrites the endpoint configuration of the first one. Hence, the expected first server is not running at all.

2nd try: multiple Jetty endpoints.

One may try something like (after creating Jetty endpoint(s) and adding them to the context):

```
this.restConfiguration("jetty")....
this.rest("/path").... // good
...
this.restConfiguration("jetty-tls")....
this.rest("/path").... // produces exception!
```

It looks like the rest definitions are added to the Camel context. On creating routes for the second RouteBuilder, the definition from the first one is already there. Camel wants to create 2 routes with the same path and throws exception:

```
Failed to start route ... because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: jetty:...
```

Unfortunately, it is not an option to skip the rest definition in one of the builders.

Bonus try: multiple Jetty endpoints and different paths.

One expects at least this to work:

```
this.restConfiguration("jetty")....
this.rest("/path1").... // good
...
this.restConfiguration("jetty-tls")....
this.rest("/path2").... // good
```

No exceptions here, but Camel starts 3 routes!